# Typing mongoose findOne query when projection object is provided

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typing

FIRST OF ALL it's a typescript only question. I don't care about the js part.

My final goal is to type a simple mongoose find with a projection object.

let's say movie as 3 fields :

- name -> string,
- email -> string
- isGood -> boolean

```js
Movie.findOne({ year: { $gte: 1980, $lte: 1989 }, {isGood: -1}, function(err, movie) {
  // Here I want ts compiler to understand that returned object does not have the isGood property
});
```

I want my returned object to be typed like this (without the isGood property since we omit it in the projection object.

```js
{
  name: string,
  email: string
}
```

Right now I have this code :

```js
type Diff<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;  // Remove types from T that are assignable to U

interface Test {
    blob: number;
    pop: number;
}

interface UserProfile {
    id: string
    email: string
    image: string | null
    isAdmin: boolean
    username: string
    reviews: string[],
    test: Test
}

type ExcludedTypes<T, U> = {
    [K in Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>]: T[K]
}

type PartialFrom<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: number | PartialFrom<T[P]>;
}

const excludeFn = <K extends Record<string, any>, T extends PartialFrom<K>>(user: K, projection: T): ExcludedTypes<K, T> => {
    const newUser: K = {
        ...user
    };

    Object.keys(projection).forEach((key) => {
        delete newUser[key];
    })

    return user;
}

const full: UserProfile = {
    id: "reareaz",
    email: "rezrza",
    image: null,
    isAdmin: false,
    username: "rezaraz",
    reviews: ["test"],
    test: {
        blob: 1221,
        pop: 122,
    }
}

const projection = {
    email: -1,
    image: -1,
    reviews: -1,
}

const filteredObject = excludeFn(full, projection);

interface PartialUserProfile {
    id: string
    isAdmin: boolean
    username: string
}

// this is just used to test that filteredObject is properly typed 
const ppp = (a: PartialUserProfile): void => { }

// it should fail because email is not in filtered object anymore
ppp(filteredObject);
```

So the goal here is to create a types function that take a full object as first argument, a partial object and return fields of full object that are NOT in partial object.

My exemple above work only on first level properties :

It work :

```js
const full = {
  image: 'string',
  isFalse: true
}

const projection = {
 image: -1
}

// will not have image property
const filteredObject = excludeFn(full, projection);
```

Won't work :

```js
const full = {
  image: 'string',
  pasta: {
    isGood: true,
    brand: 'mypastabrand'
  }
}

const projection = {
 pasta: {
   isGood: -1
 }
}

const filteredObject = excludeFn(full, projection);
```

This won't work because my type :

```js
type ExcludedTypes<T, U> = {
    [K in Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>]: T[K]
}
```

Does not go more than one level deep and that's where I'm stuck

Comment: Could you provide examples of expressions that you would expect to have type "other"?

Comment: I don't know of "typescript" way to check this, I'd use something like: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/isPlainObject.js

Comment: Can you show how you intend to use such a check?  Do you really want string literal types `"other"` and `"object"` in some code?  If you could provide a little more context it would be helpful.  TS describes JS, and in JS everything is either a primitive or an object.  In TS object types are something like `object | null` while primitives are something like `string | number | boolean | bigint | symbol | undefined`.  I'd want to understand the use case more before I'd recommend using a conditional type though.

Comment: I think the distinction you draw between classic JS objects and objects created by newing a `class` is a false one.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's no way to do this. Plain objects are assignable to things typed by classes, and visa versa. For example, this is legal: `class A {}; const a: A = {};`. So saying `A` is a class type and `{}` isn't isn't meaningful. Hopefully someone who is really good with conditional expressions can prove me wrong.

Comment: Edited my answer, hope it will be easier to understand. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: I wouldn't do that, you try to mix weak and strong types, why don't you want to create types for every usecase of yours?
YOu'll have to create a lot of types, yes, but the advantages I see are
1) unambiguous code, you don't need to evaluate in your head what type will be there in a result.
2) no need in excludeFn because mongoose will do that for you. So you'll have something like that

    Movie.findOne({ year: { $gte: 1980, $lte: 1989 }, {isGood: -1}, function(err,movie:AnotherMovieType) {});

Comment: @dulebov.artem I get your point and that might be my only solution. But still prefer something automatic if it is possible over manually typing every time I have a query with projection

Comment: Isn't the `excludeFn` supposed to return `newUser` instead of `user`?

Comment: @Vasanth Yes but as I said I only check typescript compiler types, this function is just here for typing